# Failure 3706 Syntax error: Invalid SQL statement

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

```
create procedure InsertEmp
(
 IN in_eno INTEGER,
 IN in_fname VARCHAR(30),
 IN in_lanme VARCHAR(30),
 IN in_DOB DATE,
 IN in_JoinedDate DATE,
 IN in_DepartmentNo BYTEINT
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
END;
```

While executing above procedure through unix server facing

> Failure 3706 Syntax error: Invalid SQL statement.

Comment: How do you run this in on the Unix server, BTEQ? Then you need to put the source code in a file and `.COMPILE` it. Besides that the Select will fail, too.

Comment: @dnoeth i should put SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE; in a file and i should trigger it as .COMPILE FILE <path of the file> right?

Comment: No, the full source code of the SP must be in that file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an INTO clause in the procedure you posted, in order to compile in any environment (BTEQ, SQL*Assistant, et al).

Roughly like this:

```
create table EMPLOYEE (eno INTEGER);

replace procedure InsertEmp
(
 IN in_eno INTEGER
 )
BEGIN
DECLARE l_eno INTEGER;
SELECT top 1 eno INTO l_eno FROM EMPLOYEE;
END;
```